# ls and print command

Tags: printing, ls

I am running this command "ls -lah -lF | grep /$ | awk '{print $2,$5,$9}' >> test.txt"

when it runs and sends the results to the text file the output is all in one row. How do I get it to formate each directory in a row?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't in one line. Just checked. Check, how your editor handles Unix line endings.

Comment: I am running the command on  a Mac. Is there another why get the same result

Comment: OK, I do not know exactly how it would work on mac, but:

* change the awk to print the "\n" (so `awk '{print $2,$5,$9}"\n"'` )

* if that does not help, show the output of `ls -lah -lF | grep /$ | awk '{print $2,$5,$9}' | xxd -g1 | head`, so all the character codes would be visible.

Comment: When I run the command to send command "echo -e $(ls -lah -l */.*|awk '{print $2,$5,$9}') >> $logfile"to a text file it output everything in one line. How do I get it to make in a neat colume?

Comment: Change the **awk** command just as I described:
```awk '{print $2,$5,$9}"\n"'```. The **"\n"** is the important part.